# How add some condition such $\lim_{u\to+\infty}\int_{a}^{+\infty}f(x,u)dx=\int_{a}^{+\infty}\lim_{u\to+\infty}f(x,u)dx$

Tags: analysis

**Question:**
if

> $$\lim_{u\to+\infty}\int_{a}^{+\infty}f(x,u)dx=\int_{a}^{+\infty}\lim_{u\to+\infty}f(x,u)dx\tag{1}$$

My question: then $f(x,u)$ must have Need to add what condition?

**I know this:**

if

> $$\lim_{u\to u_{0}}\int_{a}^{b}f(x,u)dx=\int_{a}^{b}\lim_{u\to u_{0}}f(x,u)dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(x,u_{0})dx$$
>   then $f(x,u)$ must add continuous  on $[a,b]$.

**(2): and I know this**

if

> $$\lim_{u\to u_{0}}\int_{a}^{+\infty}f(x,u)dx=\int_{a}^{+\infty}\lim_{u\to u_{0}}f(x,u)dx=\int_{a}^{+\infty} f(x,u_{0})dx$$
>   then $$\int_{a}^{+\infty}f(x,u)dx$$ 
>   converges uniformly on each interval $[\alpha,\beta]$,where $u_{0}\in [\alpha,\beta]$

**But for $(1)$ I can't find.Thank you,and I guess: $f(x,u)$ must Uniformly bounded
?Is ture? why? Thank you for your help**

Comment: Just being dominated by an $L^1$ function should work right?

Comment: Hello,I don't understand your mean.Thank you

Comment: Please specify the context of your question : are you working with Riemann integrable function ? Lebesgue integrability ? Or other kind of notion of integrability ?

Answer (score 0):

If I am correct, Prahlad suggests using the Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Let $(u_n)$ be any sequence tending to infinity and let $f_n(x) = f(x, u_n)$.

Now suppose there exists a function $g(x) \in L^1$ such that for any sequence, say $(s_n)$, such that $\lim_n s_n \to \infty$ we have that $|f(x, s_n)| \leq g(x)$.

Then by Lebesgues Dominated Convergence Theorem, we have that $\lim_n \int f_n(x) dx = \int \lim_n f_n(x) dx$.